# Make money bundle

Tags: meaning

Let’s say that i have 200 pieces of a $100 bill . And i want to bring them together in bundle. Would it be correct to say :

> I need to turn bills into two bundles of 100 pieces each of a $100 bills .

Comment: Are you saying you have $20,000 in $100 bills?

Comment: Yes i have $20,000

Comment: What does "have 200 pieces of a $100 bill" mean? Do you mean: you have 200 bills with a face value of $100? The short form of that is: I have 200 $100-dollar bills. aka banknotes.

Comment: Yes i mean that

Comment: Note that "200 pieces of a $100 bill" literally means "one single $100 bill ripped into 200 tiny shreds," which is not what I assume you want to say.  Unlike the word **money**, the word **bill** is an ordinary count noun and takes an ordinary plural without needing "pieces of". As @Lambie says, the correct form is "I have two hundred $100 bills."

Answer (score 1):

Money is said to be put into bundles or stacks of 1,000 units each.

In the US, bundles have bands: the bands have straps around them.

Here is an **official guide to creating bundles with straps** for deposit with the Federal Reserve (the US Central Bank) for the different denominations (a denomination means a banknote of $10.00, $20.00, $50.00, etc.).

This is regulated by the Federal Reserve Bank and the American Banking Association.

"A strap is a package of 100 notes.
All straps must contain 100 notes of the same denomination and must have only one band around them."

[Federal Reserve rules for banks re bundles of cash money](https://www.frbservices.org/resources/financial-services/cash/depositing-ordering/visual-reference-guide.html)

**Question**: **Would it be correct to say** this?

"I need to turn bills into two bundles of 100 pieces each of a $100 bills."

***Answer:*** **I need to put 200 $100 bills into two stacks or bundles.**

(or **two hundred one-hundred dollar bills**)

Comment: Is “two bundle of 100 pieces each of a $100 bills” wrong or correct ?

Comment: I believe I have already corrected you. Piece is incorrect. :) They are called bills. I have two five-dollar bills. or: I have two $5 bills. :)

Comment: Actually i tried to use it like “ a pack of six bottles of coke”.

Comment: Please capitalize your first person pronoun. :) A six-pack of coke.

Comment: **Coke** is a mass noun, **bill** is count noun.  You can't use mass noun constructions with count nouns. The construction should be more like "a pack of cookies," since **cookie** is a count noun just like **bill**.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Who is using mass noun construction with count nouns? How is that relevant to my answer?

Comment: The OP is, by trying to say "pieces each of $100 bills".  It's relevant to your comment that "piece is incorrect".  I am agreeing with you.

Answer (score 0):

They are generally known as *bundles*, in my experience. In America, they are sometimes known as *straps*, from the special bands used to hold them together, though that might only apply to those in the standard sizes with standard coloured bands. May also be called a *wad*, but the precise implications of a *wad of money* vary between dialects. I understand that in some it specifically means a *roll* of paper money, rather than a bundle of flat sheets.

Comment: Never occurred to me before, but I suppose this is where the phrase 'to make a bundle' meaning 'to make a lot of money' comes from.

Comment: @fred2: I've always assumed so.

Answer (score 0):

You would normally refer a large amount of paper cash in a neat stack as, well, a "stack". If you have several stacks packaged together (like it came new from the Fed), you might hear "brick".